# What are some verses that say clearly say Brahman is immortal?

Tags: vedas, brahman

Very know that Brahman is supreme God.

So are there any verse from the vedas that say clearly say Brahman is immortal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the few verses from Scripture saying Brahman is Immortal

> This Purusha who wakes when all sleep, creating what was desired is
> certainly ‘the pure,’ that is **Brahman and that is said to be
> immortal**. All worlds are fastened on that; none passes beyond that.
> This verily is that.(Katha Upanishad 2.2.8)
>
> Root up and branches down is this ancient asvattha tree, that (its
> source) is pure. **That is Brahman and that alone is called
> immortal**. On that, do all worlds depend and none passes beyond that.
> This verily is that. (Katha Upanishad 2.3.1)
>
> The purusha alone is all this universe—Karma and Tapas. **All this is
> Brahman, the highest and the immortal**; who knows this as seated in
> the cavity of the heart, unties the knot of ignorance even here, Oh
> good looking youth! (Mundaka Upanishad 2.1.10)
>
> What is bright, what is smaller than the small, in what are centred
> all the world and those that live in them is this **immortal
> Brahma**n. That is prana, that is speech and mind. That is true and
> immortal; good looking youth. Strike thy mind upon that which should
> be struck by the mind.(Mundaka Upanishad 2.2.2)
>
> **All this before is immortal Brahman**; certainly all behind is Brahman; all to the south and to the north; all bellow and all alone
> stretched out, i.e., extended, all this is certainly Brahman, the
> highest.(Mundaka Upanishad 2.2.11)

Comment: Thanks for the answer